# How to recover a parachain?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, xcm, relay-chain

I was working on `Xcm` functionality and using the function `limitedTeleportAsset` to transfer assets from one parachain to another parachain. I performed `runtime upgrade` in one parachain and suddenly that parachain `stopped` producing blocks. Is there any way to `recover the parachain`, so that i need not start it again.

Comment: how are you running your chain? can you give more information about your testing environment

Comment: I am running my  chain by connecting it to relay chain using the following command


./target/release/parachain-template-node --name a1 --collator --force-authoring --chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json --base-path /tmp/parachain/a1 --port 40333 --ws-port 8844 -- --execution wasm --chain ../polkadot/customSpecRawlocal.json --port 30343 --ws-port 9977 --bootnodes /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWFLacAh5hP92e88mHbFPwqvXegtrmFVs7XVeKL3eG3Qya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decide the best solution it really depends of what cause the problem, any idea what was wrong with the upgrade? If is something wrong with the upgrade you might want to fix it and perform the runtime upgrade again, see [What is the proper way of executing a runtime upgrade on a parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/what-is-the-proper-way-of-executing-a-runtime-upgrade-on-a-parachain)

If you have a backup you will be able to launch your parachain with that backup, see how here: [Parachain recovery](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5686/parachain-recovery).

If not you might need to use sudo privilegies to revert unfinalized blocks: [How to revert a bricked chain due to bad setCode](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/283/how-to-revert-a-bricked-chain-due-to-bad-setcode)

There are 2 previous answers on StackExchange about this topic, they are more theoretical but it might be interesting for you to read:

- [How do I recover quickly if the number of healthy nodes for my parachain reaches zero?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3581/how-do-i-recover-quickly-if-the-number-of-healthy-nodes-for-my-parachain-reaches)
- [How to unbrick a Substrate Chain? --revert?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/168/how-to-unbrick-a-substrate-chain-revert)

If not, in case you are running it locally you can `revert` the unfinalized blocks: [How to revert a bricked chain due to bad setCode](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/283/how-to-revert-a-bricked-chain-due-to-bad-setcode)

For parachains in production, there is a whole discussion around parachain recoveries in the Polkadot Forum: [How to Recover a Parachain](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/how-to-recover-a-parachain/673?page=2).